# modinfo some module problem with understanding parameter

Tags: drivers, kernel, 20.04

Example from

```
modinfo i915 | fgrep parm
force_probe:Force probe the driver for specified devices. See                               
CONFIG_DRM_I915_FORCE_PROBE for details. (charp)
```

what means (charp)? true/false or some Nr.  Or something else?

```
grep CONFIG_DRM_I915_FORCE_PROBE /boot/config-5.4.0-47-generic 
CONFIG_DRM_I915_FORCE_PROBE=""
```

says nothing to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Description can be found in [linux/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/Kconfig](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/Kconfig):

```
config DRM_I915_FORCE_PROBE
    string "Force probe driver for selected new Intel hardware"
    depends on DRM_I915
    help
      This is the default value for the i915.force_probe module
      parameter. Using the module parameter overrides this option.

      Force probe the driver for new Intel graphics devices that are
      recognized but not properly supported by this kernel version. It is
      recommended to upgrade to a kernel version with proper support as soon
      as it is available.

      Use "" to disable force probe. If in doubt, use this.

      Use "<pci-id>[,<pci-id>,...]" to force probe the driver for listed
      devices. For example, "4500" or "4500,4571".

      Use "*" to force probe the driver for all known devices.
```

So apparently it is a string, in which case I assume that *charp* means *char pointer*.